# How can I compare .dsql (Azure SQL DW and PDW) files in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, diff

If I invoke the file diff tool in Visual Studio 2015 on a text file with extension .dsql (Azure SQL DW and PDW SQL script) I get the error:

> Error occurred during difference operation: Cannot execute the configured tool

Diff works as expected for other text file extensions.

Visual Studio Professional 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 using VSTS source control.

Comment: I had a bounty on this but there's no answer that really solves the problem. It's strange Stack Overflow says I "must award this bounty" but the question hasn't been answered. (?)

Answer (score 2):

You can compare text files by using the default file-comparison tool integrated with Visual Studio, the [Diff window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/compare-files).

However, you can associate a file type with a third-party compare tool using these configuration [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/associate-file-type-file-comparison-tool).

### Updated:

Alternatively, you can give a try to [WinMerge](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/) tool for comparing the files, it's easy and [open source](http://winmerge.org/downloads/):

> 1. **Open Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation** under the **Tools > Options** menu in Visual Studio.
> 2. Click on **Configure User Tools …** and the Configure User Tools dialog will become available.
>
>    - Add the WinMerge details for the Compare Tool. Click on the **Add …** button on the **Configure User Tools** dialog and configure as per the screenshot below. The arrow button next to the arguments text box exposes details about the information that Visual Studio can provide the tool being configured.
>    - The configured arguments are:
>
>      ```
>      /e /u /wl /wr /dl %6 /dr %7 %1 %2
>      ```
> 3. WinMerge [Command Line Options](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html)
>
>    ```
>    /e    Enables WinMerge to be closed with a single Esc key press.
>    /u  Prevents WinMerge from adding either the left or right hand side  
>        file path to the Most Recently Used (MRU) list.
>    /wl Opens left hand side as read-only.
>    /wr Opens right hand side as read-only.
>    /dl Description for left hand side title bar.
>    /dr Description for right hand side title bar.
>    ```

Comment: Can you clarify - your link text says "Visual Studio 2015 Update 4" but the actual link connects to TFS 2015 Update 4. I don't believe there is any such thing as a Visual Studio 2015 update past 3? Could be wrong. See https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-version-history

Comment: sorry for the previous wrong link see **Updated** in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the effort put into your answer, but this doesn't really address the problem, which is to make visual studio's built-in DIFF tool work correctly.

Comment: Yes, I can understand :(

Comment: I have a lot of searched and googled to your problem but Diff tool solution didn't found except alternative of WinMerge.

Comment: Yes, I can see you did and I'm grateful for that. That's pretty much where I ended up too - people can reproduce this problem but nobody has a solution, except to use a different tool. It seems a shame to have to do that.